# How can I remove a file named "InstallESD.dmg" on my Mac?

Tags: macos

How can I remove a file named "InstallESD.dmg" on my Mac?
I used the command 'sudo rm InstallESD.dmg',  but it didn't work

Comment: I think this question may fit better on https//apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: What was the error shown when you tried the `rm` command?

Comment: rm: InstallESD.dmg: Operation not permitted

Comment: What happens when you run with sudo?

Comment: @Lemon Does not work either with `sudo`

Comment: Here are the necessary steps: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250452068

Comment: Too complicated with possible security implications. May require owner privileges (firmware password).

Answer (score 0):

Just move the file to /tmp/. System will delete it upon next reboot.